# Spring JMS: Why CachingConnectionFactory is created always with started=false?

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, jmx, spring-jmx

I have a sample app demo working with:

- Spring Framework `4.2.5`
- ActiveMQ `5.13.3`

I have the following:

```
@Bean(name="connectionFactory")
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory selectedActiveMQConnectionFactory) throws JMSException{
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    cachingConnectionFactory.setClientId("ManolitoActiveMQ");
    cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(selectedActiveMQConnectionFactory);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(10);
    cachingConnectionFactory.createConnection().start();
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}
```

When I use the `cachingConnectionFactory.createConnection().start();` line
I can see that when my app starts it shows:

> 3370 [main] INFO  o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Established shared JMS Connection:
>   ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:sometext,clientId=ManolitoActiveMQ,started=false}

Has sense expect that message when the app starts and read `Established shared JMS Connection` but why shows `started=false`? I think should be true.

If I comment `cachingConnectionFactory.createConnection().start();` and start the app, the message shown above does not appear, ok, it is expected. But later through `JMX` when I start to send messages, I can see again

> 3370 [main] INFO  o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Established shared JMS Connection:
>   ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:sometext,clientId=ManolitoActiveMQ,started=false}

Ok it is expected, but again `started=false` appears

It is confuse in some point because the `cachingConnectionFactory.createConnection().start()` line ends with `start()` for the *Connection*

1. Therefore why practically always appears `started=false`?
2. When or how that `started` attribute would appear with `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the `started=false` is in the `toString()` of the connection - it has nothing to do with the connection factory; it relates to the connection just created.

```
logger.info("Established shared JMS Connection: " + this.connection);
```

The connection itself will be started later if needed.

Comment: Thanks by the reply Gary, understood.

Comment: I have confirmed that line from the `SingleConnectionFactory.java` class from the `initConnection()` method